# Notepad++ Remove everything before the , string?

Tags: notepad++

i have a file like this

```
100980,'text 1','text 2','email@email.net',0,0,0,0,0,''
```

I would like to remove the number at the start and end

So the file will look like the following in a nice list..

```
'text 1','text 2','email@email.net'
```

Comment: You better code a little program, I don't think Notepad++ lets you do such sophisticated editing operations.

Comment: Would be easier using OpenOffice Calc (or Microsoft Excel) open the CSV as table and remove the columns, then re-save as csv.

Comment: How many lines is that file then? Are all lines like the example?

Comment: @Sam there are 13675 lines

Answer (score 0):

One way via Excel, without coding a little program:

**Whatever you manually do to the information in your file, copy it and work on the copy !!**

- Open the copy in Notepad++. (For the following steps, open the search dialog and untick the option "only search whole words".
- I suppose the double quote (actually two single quotes) at the end of your "before" example is not intended. If it is actually part of every line in your file, search&replace the double quote (or two single quotes) with nothing (therefore deleting it)
- Then search&replace all commas with semicolons. Your file is then a valid CSV format file.
- Rename the file with the ending *.csv
- Open the file in Excel
- Delete the columns that you don't need, resave the file with ending *.csv
- Open the file with Notepad++
- Search&replace all semicolons with commas

Then you see the result.
Rename it with ending *.txt to recieve back a normal text file.

To make this a routine operation, better code a little program or (if you're the developer of it) let the program that emits the original file also write a second file in the format that you are needing here.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression (Regex) search and replace in Notepad++

Enter this as your search string

```
\d*\,('.+')(\,.*$)
```

And this as your replace string

```
$1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a two step regular expression "replace".

First step: remove the leading number:
Replace Dialog:
 
Find what:^[0-9]+,
Replace with: (leave empty)
Search Mode: tick Regular expression
Replace all

Second step: remove the trailing comma digits and ending single quotes:
Replace Dialog:
Find what:,([0-9]+,)*''$
Replace with: (leave empty)
Search Mode: tick Regular expression
Replace all

If something goes wrong, use undo. If the two single quotes in your example are unintended, just leave them out in the second regular expression.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

Find what: `^\d+,|(?:,\d+)+,''$`
Replace with: `Leave empty`